# How can I accurately find the distance between two drones over moderate distances?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, distance, drone

I am currently taking part in a project in which I am building drones using Arduinos and Raspberry Pis, and I need to be able to measure the distance between the drones. After some research, I realized that many people use ultrasonic sensors.

However, I want to build a system that can measure the distance through walls and over moderate distances (up to 100 meters.) I figured that ultrasonic sensors won't have this range, and might not work through walls. I am honestly stumped with how to solve this problem.

Is there a way to do this, or is that just not a practical idea?

I want to have an accuracy of at least within half a meter.

Comment: GPS? This is one of those problems that's much harder than it sounds.

Comment: I thought about that, but the accuracy of GPS is not accurate enough. It's normally around 2 meters, but I need within half a meter.

Comment: Differential GPS will get you centimeter precision rapidly but you really need to be able to see most of the sky

Comment: second the diff gps. also, depending of the application, if your drones have cameras some computer vision *could* work

Comment: Walls are a problem with GPS.  Walls imply buildings, which have roofs which block the GPS signal.

Comment: Maybe some PRNG-modulated GHz signal reflected off the other drone and some correlation signal processing to find the round trip delay? Sounds not so easy.

Comment: Is it always in the same building? You could place BLE/WIFI dongles on fixed places and use RSSI.

Comment: Ideally the project would be indoors and outdoors, but we would settle for outdoors where we can see most of the sky. It will not always be in the same building, and should be able to work anywhere

Comment: Try this: "SparkFun GPS-RTK ZED-F9R (with 3D IMU, ~ 0.2 meter accuracy) - US$300":
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16344. Cheers..

Comment: I think by now you should be getting the feeling that this is not a practical idea. There have been many, many posts on this site over the years asking for similar systems for everything from games to Covid-19 trackers. There is no easy-to-do solution.

Answer (score 0):

At about 1 foot per nanosecond, you might use fast risetime LASER pulses, off corner_reflectors. This is how we precision_range the moon, using  several square feet of optical reflectors put in place during Apollo.

You might also use swept_frequency radio waves, such as what planes use to determine altitude. You'd need a repeater on the collaborating drone. The phase shift sets the distance. Calibration of baseline delays would be needed.

The 800 and 900 MHZ ISM bands might work and might be legal.

Comment: Hitting the corner reflector and detecting the tiny return pulse with adequate bandwidth is ... left as an exercise for the reader :-)